# Unable to Create New Database with EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2014

I have SQL Server 2014 Developer Edition and using Entity Framework 5.0. When i am trying to hit page first time, entity framework is failing to create new database and getting the below error message

```
The provider manifest given is not of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderManifest'.

ArgumentException: The provider manifest given is not of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderManifest'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.GetSqlVersion(StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection) +2600711
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection) +213
   System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection) +21
   EFProviderWrapperToolkit.DbProviderServicesBase.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection) +150
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase() +84
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection connection) +83
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists() +70
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration) +44
   System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +62
   System.Data.Entity.<>c__DisplayClass2`1.<SetInitializerInternal>b__0(DbContext c) +70
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c__DisplayClass8.<PerformDatabaseInitialization>b__6() +19
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +60
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +181
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c) +7
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +110
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +185
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase() +73
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ForceOSpaceLoadingForKnownEntityTypes() +60
   System.Data.Entity.DbContext.System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter.get_ObjectContext() +25
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: which database initializer are you using?

Comment: I am using MigrateToLatestVersion

Comment: I found this information reference to my issue (https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/202) - As I can't upgrade to EF 6, so is there a workaround for EF 5.0

Comment: are you asking here if there is a way to not be affected by a bug in the software without updating to the version which has a fix provided by the vendor?  A bug which was triaged 2 years ago?

Comment: I am asking if there is any workaround